# Why is the value fetched from main memory when printing?

Tags: java

Given the following code. When I uncomment the print statement, the Consumer reads the value from main memory (and detects a change).
When I leave it commented, no change is detected (both assuming non-volatile of course).

Why is that? Is it just "random" that the compiler decided in this case it's a good idea not to use the cache?

```
public class Counter {
    private /*volatile*/ int val;

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public synchronized void increment() {
        this.val++;
    }
}

public class Producer extends Thread {
    private final Counter counter;

    public Producer(Counter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (counter.getVal() < 5) {
            counter.increment();
            System.out.println("Producer: incrementing count to " + counter.getVal());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Producer: terminating");
    }
}

public class Consumer extends Thread {
    private final Counter counter;

    public Consumer(Counter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int localValue = -1;
        while (true) {
//            System.out.println("I see: " + counter.getVal());
            if (localValue != counter.getVal()) {
                System.out.println("Consumer: detected count change " + counter.getVal());
                localValue = counter.getVal();
            }
            if (counter.getVal() >= 5) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer: terminating");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a data race. Your `getVal` should definitely be synchronized on the same object `increment` is synchronized on.

Comment: I mean volatile is enough, I don’t really care that the value being read is really the last value that was set. I’m confused though why it’s working fine when doing a println before